# Temporarily stop consuming RabbitMQ messages and resume later

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, amqp-client

I use Java's rabbitmq-client (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client) and I need to implement the following scenario:

- While receiving Rabbit messages, I may need to pause Rabbitmq consumption from  particular queues if I suspect that all awaiting data will not fit in memory.
- After I processed some messages, I need to open consumption again for the following set of messages.
- Repeat as needed.

What would be the best way to implement pause/resume of listening from a RabbitMQ queue using the amqp-client Java library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which method you're using to consume messages, so I assume you are using [`basicConsume`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) to subscribe to messages from a queue.

As [that document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) mentions, you can use `basicCancel` to stop consuming from a queue. You would then use `basicConsume` when you wish to start again.

Be sure to use `basicQos` to set a reasonable prefetch count.

Comment: I'd love to know how to do the same using Spring-rabbit (without touching amqp-client directly). Any idea?

Comment: I suggest searching the code (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp) or asking a question on the various support channels. Several Spring developers are active on stack overflow.

Comment: Were you able to find out how we can do this with spring-amqp?